# Camel junit test http component with bean component

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have route in my camel context like this:-

```
<camel:route id="xxx">
 <camel:from uri="direct:test"></camel:from>
 <camel:to uri="bean:testProcessor"></camel:to>
 <camel:to  uri="{{testUrl}}"></camel:to>
 <camel:to uri="bean:responseHandler"></camel:to>
</camel:route>
```

i want to test the whole route .so whenever i sent request to direct:test it will call the testProcessor and then calls the http service with testUrl and then calls the responseHandler bean element. How can i test this? Most importantly here stubbing the http service

Answer (score 1):

I have having some trouble understanding your exact use case so I will point you towards camel's AdviceWithRouteBuilder library you can use for testing.  I am not 100% fluid in the camel xml based version so I will use Java DSL for my sample.  Here is the link to some camel documentation you can use as a reference:
http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

//sample route

```
from("direct:myNormalInput").routeId("xxx")
    .to("myBean", "myMethod").id("enrichmentBean")
    .to("http://myawesomeurl").id("HttpCaller")
    .to("myResponseBean", "myMethod").id("responseHandler");
```

//Sample Unit Test

```
public void myTest throws Exception {
    context.getRouteDefinition("xxx").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        //You can replace your normal route's from statement
        replaceFromWith("direct:testEntry");
        //Swap out your enrichmentBean with a replace or remove it if you prefer
        weaveById("enrichmentBean").replace().to("myTestBean", "myTestMethod");
        //mock out your http call with a different url or a fake endpoint
        weaveById("HttpCaller").replace().to("http://myTestUrl");
        //extract your message at any point in processing to do some validation work
        weaveById("responseHandler").after().to("mock:extract");
    }
    context.start();

    template.sendBody("direct:testEntry", "myTestBody");

    MockEndpoint test = getMockEndpoint("mock:extract");
    int messageCount =  test.getReceivedExchanges().size();
    assertEquals(1, messageCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a route with Jetty consumer on the fly in your unit tests. This way, you can actually test the web service behaviour. I tend to do this when writing integration tests and can be very useful. Otherwise, as Matthew suggested, you can just mock it out.

Comment: Could you provide an example for using Jetty consumer on the fly in unit tests?